# PHP creating array of values with keys

Tags: php, mysql

Im wanting to create a table to display a list of data from the database. But the values aren't stored in rows in a table but instead are separated by each value having its own column.

**So my sample Data:**

```
ID  Email           Value    
1   david@a.com     ABC    
1   david@a.com     DEF    
1   david@a.com     GHI    
2   jonathan@a.com  ABC    
2   jonathan@a.com  DEF    
2   jonathan@a.com  GHI
```

**Im wanting to display it as:**

```
ID  Email           Value1  Value2  Value3    
1   david@a.com     ABC     DEF     GHI    
2   jonathan@a.com  ABC     DEF     GHI
```

**My Code:**

```
$query1 = "SELECT wp_users.ID, user_email, VALUE FROM wp_users LEFT JOIN wp_cimy_uef_data on wp_users.ID = wp_cimy_uef_data.USER_ID";
$listEmail = array();
$listValues = array();

// Start the Load
$statement = $db->query($query1);
if ( $statement->rowCount() == 0 )
{
    echo '<strong>List is Empty</strong>';
} else foreach($statement as $row):

    $ID = htmlspecialchars($row['ID']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($row['user_email']);
    $value = htmlspecialchars($row['VALUE']);

    $listEmail = array_fill_keys($ID, $email);
    $listValues = array_fill_keys($ID, $value);

endforeach; 
mysqli_close($db);

print_r($listEmail);
```

Comment: Use a GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: Id like to do it in php if all possible

Comment: Yes, you could do it in PHP but the best way would be through changing the query. I had to do something similar in Oracle, and ended up using their PIVOT function. I'm assuming there's a similar feature in MySQL...

Comment: Sadly, MySQL doesn't have any functionality like Oracle's PIVOT and UNPIVOT.... perhaps next release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could structure your loop like this:

```
$table_rows = array();

foreach($statement as $row) {
    $ID = htmlspecialchars($row['ID']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($row['user_email']);
    $value = htmlspecialchars($row['VALUE']);

    if (empty($table_rows[$ID])) {
        $table_rows[$ID] = array(
            'email' => $email,
            'values' => array(),
        );
    }

    $table_rows[$ID]['values'][] = $value;

}
```

Or you could use a group by in your query.

Comment: Using this method how could i print out the contents in a formated matter?  foreach ($table_rows as $value) {
      echo $value . "<br />";
   }

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_email, 
GROUP_CONCAT(wp_users.value) 
FROM wp_users LEFT JOIN wp_cimy_uef_data on wp_users.ID = wp_cimy_uef_data.USER_ID 
GROUP BY wp_users.user_email
```

Indeed use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/) to concat the value column's and GROUP BY to group on user_email.

Comment: this does work and i thank you, however i was hoping to do it in php because i want to be able to remove values from this down the road. Say if one of the values was a the 3rd string in the values list id like to remove it. ALSO so i can display each row with a header to make it easier to read and sort.

Comment: Can't you just delete that value for that user id? E.g. `DELETE 'ABC' FROM table WHERE ID = '1'`

Comment: No unfortunately not this is for a report so the data must remain.